# Angular app function to read an irregular json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an angularjs app that reads data from a json that has a structure similar to the following:

```
[ { "name" : "TIER 1",
        "children" : [ 
            { "children" : [ "ENGL-1301","HIST-1301"],
            },
            { "children" : [ {"children" : [{ "course" : "SPCH 1311","term" : "Spring 2012"} ]}, "SPCH-1311","SPCH-1315","SPCH-1321"],
              "name" : "Speaking and Listening",

            },
            { "children" : [ "MATH-1314","MATH-1414","MATH-1316"],
              "name" : "Quantitative Reasoning", "subcategory2" : [  ]
            },
            { "children" : [ "ARTS-1311","ARTS-1312","ARTS-1313"],
              "name" : "Wellness and The Human Experience","subcategory2" : [  ]
            }
          ]
      },
      { "name" : "TIER 2",
        "children" : [ 
            { "children" : [ {"children" : [{ "course" : "ENGL 1302","term" : "Summer 2012"} ]}, "ENGL-1302" ],
              "name" : "Qualitative Reasoning, Literacy and Research",
            },
            { "children" : [ {"children" : [{ "course" : "GOVT 2301","term" : "Spring 2012"},
                                { "course" : "PSYC 2301","term" : "Summer 2012"} ]}, "HIST-1302","HIST-2301","HIST-2328"],
              "name2" : "Self and Society",
            },
            { "children" : [ "ARTS-1301","ARTS-1303","ARTS-1304","DANC-2303"],
              "name2" : "Humanity, Creativity and the Aesthetic Experience",
            },
          ]
      }
    ]
```

As you can see, the json file does not look well orgranized. It has a few elements which has `children` and these `children` have more elements called `children`. So in order to read this json file into an angular app, i would like to define a function named `isemptychildren()` to check if a particular children element has more subcategories of children.

I apologize if the question is getting confusing but i didnt know of a better way to explain it. How do i write this function?

Answer (score 1):

A robust check which works in all browsers is to use the `Object.keys()` function recursively on all elements, example:

```
function isEmptyChildren(hash){
    return (Object.keys(hash).indexOf("chidren") == -1) ? true : false;
}
```

Though for your own sanity's sake, I would advise you to modify that data structure if possible to use a different naming convention.

Comment: i wish i could but that is the way i am getting the data from the server :-( . I ll try your method

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides a utility function to simplify property existence tests:

```
function isEmptyChildren(item){
    return angular.isUndefined(item.children);
}
```

You can see in the AngularJS source code that it does a typeof check:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L408